Only getting CORs issues when caching is enabled
I'm getting a very odd combination of CORs issues when trying to do a fetch request for an object hosted in R2 (Cloudflare S3 equivalent):

If I disable cache in devtools:


Then, I have no CORs issues.
Similarly, if I disable the cache then re-enable it, I have no issues. But ... if I "clear the browser cache", then refresh the page, I'll get CORs issues.
This is happening when trying to do a fetch request for an R2 bucket with the following CORs policy:
[
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "https://localhost:3000",
      "http://localhost:3000"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET",
      "HEAD",
      "POST",
      "PUT",
      "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
      "*"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]

which should allow all CORs requests. What could be happening?
One thing to note -- Cloudflare only returns the proper CORs headers if the request contains the Origin header.
Here's a script I used to test CORS vs non-CORs versions:
#!/bin/bash

# config
url="$1"
origin="${2:-http://localhost:3000}"

if [ -z "$url" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <url> [origin]"
    echo "example: $0 https://your-r2-url.com/file http://localhost:3000"
    exit 1
fi

echo "testing cors for url: $url"
echo "using origin: $origin"
echo

# test 1: fresh request
echo "=== testing fresh request ==="
curl -si -h "origin: $origin" \
     -h "cache-control: no-cache" \
     "$url" | grep -v "^$"

# get response headers and extract etag
etag=$(curl -si -h "origin: $origin" "$url" | grep -i "etag" | tr -d '\r' | cut -d' ' -f2)

if [ ! -z "$etag" ]; then
    echo
    echo "=== testing cached request with etag: $etag ==="
    curl -si -h "origin: $origin" \
         -h "if-none-match: $etag" \
         "$url" | grep -v "^$"
fi

I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in both cases.

I don't know about CloudFlare and R2 in particular, but have seen similar issues with S3 and CloudFront. The thing is, if the file is directly returned from S3, the CORS headers it sets are passed through as is. When the file is served from the CloudFront cache, it will (or won't) set CORS headers depending on how it's configured. You need to configure CORS both in S3 and CloudFront. Use an HTTP client like curl or Postman to send appropriate headers (If-Modified-Since or such) to specifically test cached and uncached responses.

If I use fetch(url, { cache: 'no-store' }), then the issue goes away. So, it's got something to do with caching. I don't think it's a Cloudflare issue, since I used a script to check headers when using e-tag vs non e-tag version, and the headers looked OK in both versions.

I solved the issue with:
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                cache: 'no-cache'
            });

To be honest, I'm not sure what's happening. My hypothesis is that since no-cache still makes a conditional request to the server, it is refreshing some important headers?
